# Oracle SQL query to combine columns from multiple tables and count using group by

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Table T1:
Column T1A
Column insertdate (TIMESTAMP(6), indexed)
Column T1B

Table T2:
Column T1B
Column T2name
Column T2C

Table T3:
Column T2C
Column T3name

Select T1A, count(0) 
from T1 
where (insertdate between trunc(sysdate) - 2 and trunc(sysdate) - 1) group by T1A;
```

Produces the count of yesterday’s records in T1 for each T1A value.

```
Select tbl2.T2name, tbl3.T3name 
from T2 tbl2, T3 tbl3 
where tbl2.T1B in (select tbl1.T1A from T1 tbl1 
                   where (insertdate between trunc(sysdate) - 2 and trunc(sysdate) - 1)
                   group by T1A) 
and tbl2.T2C = tbl3.T2C;
```

Returns the names of the columns in T2 and T3 that map to values in column T1A.

Now I want to combine the two so the first query contains the names instead of the key field (T1A) which is not meaningful to the reader: Report T2name, T3name, count of yesterday’s records in T1 for each T1A value.

Obviously those are not the real table and column names. If I have made a mistake in the syntax please ignore as it has not been run as is. All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please read the help on creating a [mcve]

Comment: Your query does not produce the count of yesterday's records, it produces the count of records from two days ago. If you want yesterday's records, the where clause should be `... between trunc(sysdate) - 1 and trunc(sysdate)`. Also, question for you: if a record has a time portion of the timestamp of exactly 00:00:00.000000, should it be counted for both the day before and for the day after? Using `between` as you did will have that result. (Or is it guaranteed that such a value will never happen in real life?)

Comment: The problem as stated doesn't seem to make much sense. It is reasonable to ask for T2name if T1B is primary key in Table T2 and foreign key in table T1. But what is the relationship between T2 and T3 (along column T2C?) If, as it seems logical, T2C is primary key in T3 and foreign key in T2, there may be more than one T2C value (and therefore T3name) for each T2name - otherwise why have a separate table T3 and not have T3name directly in T2? And if indeed there may be more than one T3name for each T2name, then what do you want in your output?

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are correct about yesterday and two days ago, sorry, did not pay much attention to that as it is insignificant to the issue. As for uniqueness, for each T1A, there will only be one T2name and T3name. The important part is figuring out a way to display a single line of output for each T1A that is returned in the first query, containing the count from table T1 and the names from the other two tables. I have found a few examples online using INNER JOIN but have not been successful in getting them to work with Oracle.

Comment: Also, having the count be off by one is insignificant to this effort since we are collecting historical data and are more interested in trends or large fluctuations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl2.T2name, tbl3.T3name, count(*)
FROM T1 tbl1, T2 tbl2, T3 tbl3 
WHERE tbl1.T1B = tbl2.T1B
AND tbl2.T2C = tbl3.T2C
AND tbl1.insertdate >= trunc(sysdate) - 2
AND tbl1.insertdate < trunc(sysdate) - 1
GROUP BY tbl2.T2name, tbl3.T3name;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked beautifully, thanks. PS. My original date subtractions were correct since the script will always be run the next day.